# Is the abbreviation “Id” acceptable in an essay?

Tags: grammar, phrases, expressions, abbreviations

If I need to write “Apple Id”, in an essay, should I write “Apple Identification”? “Id” is an abbreviation for “identification” so would it be proper to write “Apple Identification” instead?

Comment: Others have answered this question, but I'll just note that the abbreviation "id." (lowercase) often stands for "idem".

Answer (score 7):

If you read the official documentation, the feature is called

> Apple ID

That's its name. It doesn't appear to be an abbreviation of "Identification".

So it's best to refer to it the way Apple does, whether in an essay or anywhere else. Note that it's a capital I capital D.

Comment: Oh I did not know that! I actually wrote “Apple Id” on my phone and it autocorrected to “ID” and I figured it was wrong, but I guess it wasn’t! Thank you sooo much :)

Comment: Yes, “Id “ is wrong and “ID” is correct and acceptable and even preferred now for most formal writing. The mearning of “ID” is more specific than “identification, which sounds like it refers to a physical object.

Comment: "Id" is actually a technical word in psychology.

Comment: Id is used in psychoanalytical theory to denote the unconscious instinctual force. That is the unconscious *I* of each individual. This is hard to imagine of an apple. Except perhaps Steve Jobs.